# Spring Flux and ReactJs Integration not working

Tags: reactjs, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-cloud-gateway

I am developing a micro service application.Micro Services are deployed in Azure Cloud.I am using Eureka as service registry and Spring Cloud Gateway as api gateway.Now Both my react code and Spring Boot code is packeged inside single jar.

Now I am using Thymeleaf for redirecting to react index.html file for login screen

```
  thymeleaf:
   cache: false
   enabled: true
   prefix: classpath:/static/
   suffix: .html
```

WebFlux Security Config is as follows:

```
@Bean
public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http, MyJwtAuthConverter myJwtAuthConverter) {
    MyAuthManager myJwtAuthManager = new MyJwtAuthManager(authService, myJwtTokenUtility);
    myJwtAuthManager.setPasswordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder());
    AuthenticationWebFilter authenticationWebFilter = new AuthenticationWebFilter(myJwtAuthManager);
    authenticationWebFilter.setServerAuthenticationConverter(myJwtAuthConverter);
    return http.csrf().disable()
            .authorizeExchange()
            .pathMatchers("/myContext/myloginUrl",
                    "/myContext/static/**").permitAll()
            .anyExchange().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin().loginPage("myloginUrl").authenticationSuccessHandler(new RedirectServerAuthenticationSuccessHandler("/loginSuccess"))
            .authenticationFailureHandler((exchange, exception) -> Mono.error(exception))
            .and().securityContextRepository(NoOpServerSecurityContextRepository.getInstance())
            .addFilterAt(authenticationWebFilter, SecurityWebFiltersOrder.AUTHENTICATION).
            logout(logout-> logout.logoutSuccessHandler(logoutSuccessHandler("/mylogout")))
            .build();
}
```

My controller file declaration as below

```
@GetMapping("/myloginUrl")
public ModelAndView loginPage(){
    return new ModelAndView("index");
}
```

Now url change happening fine,whenever I am hitting any protected url it is redirecting to login page url as below

[http://localhost:8765/myContext/user-login](http://localhost:8765/myContext/myloginUrl)

But actual login page which is developed in react is not getting rendered.React Router config as below

```
   <BrowserRouter basename="/myContext">
        <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Login />} />
            <Route path="/myloginUrl" element={<Login />} />
            <Route path="/user" element={<User/>} />
        </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
```

In my build.gradle I have configured following thing

```
processResources {
dependsOn buildFrontend
from("${projectDir}/frontend/build/") {
    into 'static'
}
```

}

**The error I am getting is as below:**

```
{"view":null,"model":{},"status":null,"empty":false,"viewName":"index","modelMap":{},"reference":true}
```

Can anyone help why thymeleaf not able to redirect to react index.html???

Comment: That is not an error, that is just a representation of your `ModelAndView`. Wild guess you are using `@RestController` instead of `@Controller`.

Comment: Changing RestController to Controller also didn't fix the issue. Can you pls suggest what would be the solution to move to React index.html file ? both react code and java code are in same jar

Comment: I suspect it did fix the issue and you now have another issue.

Comment: Changing Rest Controller to Controller has given the error java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not resolve view with name 'index'

Comment: Which, as stated, is a different issue as you had before. Is the index.html in the location it is supposed to be.

Comment: yes It is inside static folder as I have mentioned entire react code after build get copied to static folder and thymeleaf configuration you can check in my post it is pointing to static folder.I doulbt whether modelandview work with webflux?

Comment: It does work but is it really working. How are you running this? If you are running this from your IDE a build isn't done and nothing is being copied. But as stated your initial issue has been solved as you now run into a different issue.

Comment: gradlew build -x test -Pargs=dev

java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=dev build\libs\myJar.jar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Spring WebFlux we need to configure following router function

```
@Bean
public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> customRouter(@Value("classpath:/static/index.html") Resource html) {
    return RouterFunctions.route(
            GET("/*"),
            request -> ServerResponse.ok().contentType(MediaType.TEXT_HTML).bodyValue(html)
    );
}
```